# Android resource qualifiers for Huge/Small fonts (accessibility)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have searched the documentation and have not found an answer so here we go:

Does Android have a resource qualifier to select between different resources when accessibility options are used? Like when the user sets font size to Huge.

I would like use different dimensions on some views when dealing with Huge/Small fonts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no resource qualifier for font scale. I assume you're aware of the `sp` unit for specifying text size. I would suggest either -

1. Make your layouts more flexible and sized based on their contents.
2. You can use `getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale` to determine the scale at runtime, and select or adjust your layout(s) accordingly.
3. This may cause more harm than good, and the docs explicitly say not to do this, but you could try using `sp` rather than `dp` for your various layout parameters as well.

Comment: Using `sp` for layout parameters is perfectly reasonable, if the size of the layout in question is dominated by a `TextView` or one of its subclasses. Do you recall where in the docs you saw guidance against this?

Comment: Agreed it should be fine in many cases, particularly in simple layouts. Here's the link/quote: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP - *"...you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes)"*

Comment: I'll file an issue (that'll probably get ignored, but, oh well...) to get that prose tightened up. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: heh. Yeah I can postulate a few reasons why they may not originally have intended people to use `sp` for more than text - for one it expands the breadth and required support of that API a user-configurable option. Alternatively, maybe they were trying to avoid developers shooting themselves in the foot with crazy-changing layouts based on font scale :)