# Android TextView not wrapping content when system wide font scaled larger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

In my app I'm trying to adjust this layout so it's readable when the user scales the system wide font size in Android System settings -> Display -> Font size (or in accessibility settings on some devices). Doing some digging I found out this adjusts the device configuration font scale (`getResources().getConfiguration.fontScale`) from `1.0` to `1.15`.

I'm getting some weird behavior in a `LinearLayout` where one of the `TextView`s width gets crushed, when it's set to `wrap_content`, and also doesn't reflect a set `minWidth`.

**What it looks like normally**
[image: normal]
**What it looks like when font is scaled**
[image: scaled]

Here is the `LinearLayout` in question (comments added for context in screenshot)

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sectionPaintStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- () 6 Paint Items -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sectionPaintItemToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabExpandPaintItems"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_collapse"
                app:elevation="2dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPaintItemCount"
                style="@style/Label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="0 Paint Items"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPaintAreaWarning"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_warning2"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Inner layout to consume middle width and right align the rest -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutPaintItemCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPaintItemCountStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Paint Items"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_time"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPaintTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2.5h"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:minWidth="70dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPaintTotal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="$123.22"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Why is that last `LinearLayout` containing 2 `TextView`s not properly wrapping content? I tried removing the `minWidth` incase that was causing any issues and got the same result. I don't understand why all the other layouts wrap their content properly but the last one doesn't.

And is it possible to add a resource folder for scaled system wide font?

**Edit** It appears removing margins allow the `TextView` to wrap the proper width but obviously I need the margins. 
[image: no margins]

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

***Edit Solved***
It turns out I completely forgot about an invisible element in the layout between the "Paint Items" label and the time icon. It was causing me to run out of horizontal space.

Comment: > And is it possible to add a resource folder for scaled system wide font?

[Nope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364696/1217087).

Comment: @AdamS Strange there's no resource qualifiers for font scale, especially since they moved font scaling out of accessibility settings into display settings...

Comment: Indeed, I can imagine a scenario where you might want to use an abbreviation rather than ellipsizing a full size label. Luckily I've never been pushed on that. For new devices, if a user bumps their accessibility scaling, the `dpi` qualifier for the device changes - so _everything_ scales now, not just text - so if you want to, you could certainly use a `-mdpi` qualifier or whatever on the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have used `layout_width="match_parent"` and `gravity="end"` to align your elements.

I *assume* on small devices (or with large text) you'd like the "0 Paint Items" to ellipsize when not enough space, and have the 'Time' and 'Total' fields to show at full width.

To do this, we make the following changes:

First, make the `sectionPaintItemToggle` have `0dp` width and `layout_weight="1"` - this tells Android "this should fill as much space is available".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sectionPaintItemToggle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... >
```

I removed *all* the `gravity="end"` settings.

I changed the "inner layout" (as per the comment) to be have `wrap_content` width.

I deleted the entire `layoutPaintItemCount` layout - I feel like you were trying a different way to do the "N paint items" layout.

In the end, we have something like this (I swapped in an ImageView for the FAB and just used resources I already had - I think I changed some margins too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sectionPaintStatus"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <!-- () 6 Paint Items -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sectionPaintItemToggle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fabExpandPaintItems"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPaintItemCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="0 Paint Items"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPaintAreaWarning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Inner layout to consume middle width and right align the rest -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPaintTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.5h"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPaintTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="$123.22"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The key part was to convince Android that the "N Paint Items" view was the one you wanted to shrink.

Comment: Yes I just realized what was happening. First I should have added context that this is a tablet app. I toggle the layout to hide the N paint item count on the left, and show the right aligned N item count. So since it was set to invisible, I ran out of space on the end. I completely forgot about that element. Easy fix to set visibility to gone and everything displays as it should. Thank you for taking the time and looking at it I will accept your answer since it works as well.